# Using *link rel* in a jekyll blog?

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll for my personal blog and I want to have *link rel* on my article pages that point to the *next*/*previous* article.

Is that possible with Jekyll?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
 <div id="page-navigation"> 
   <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div> 
     <div class="left"> 
       {% if page.previous.url %} 
         <a href="{{page.previous.url}}" title="Previous Post: 
            {{page.previous.title}}">&laquo; {{page.previous.title}}</a> 
        {% endif %} 
       </div> 
       <div class="right"> 
         {% if page.next.url %} 
          <a href="{{page.next.url}}" title="next Post: 
          {{page.next.title}}">{{page.next.title}} &raquo; </a> 
         {% endif %} 
       </div> 
     <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah, so I can access *page* on my blog article pages as well? I thought that may only be available on my frontabe, where I use the paginator: https://github.com/MoriTanosuke/moritanosuke.github.com/blob/master/_layouts/frontpage.html The problem I have is that I have to include the link in the *HEAD* of my posts, but that part is in my *_layout*...